# React table - Force to stop rerender cell

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I'm using React Table, I have custom Cell in one row, it's price chart component, my component is rendering the chart in that cell. But I have that update every 3 seconds, with new data, but I don't have new data for price chart component, so chart keeps rerender without any data update in table.

Can I force some cell in table, to stop rerender?